# Wrong value returned when using MIN Fuctions with nested IF - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using the following function to calulcate the min value of any array based on several criteria and getting the correct answer:

```
=MIN(IF(Table5[G]="M"; IF(Table5[Level]=A3;Table5[Salary]);"-"))
```

But I wanted to expand the function by adding an OR statement in the second IF statement:

```
 =MIN(IF(Table5[G]="M"; IF(***OR(Table5[Level]=TEXT(A2;0);Table5[Level]=VALUE(A2))**;*Table5[Salary]);"-"))
```

For the range of A2:A16 I'm getting the exact same number ( Min value ) which is incorrect.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data (and its format) I am not sure quite what is required but you are dealing with structured references that are arrays so may need syntax like this:

```
=MIN(IF((Table5[G]="M")*((Table5[Level]=A2)+(Table5[Level]=TEXT(A2;"0")));(Table5[Salary]);"-"))
```